# Reading double values from a text file

Tags: c#

Trying to read data from a text file using a C# application. There're multiple lines of data and each of them start with an integer and then followed by bunch of double values. A part of the text file looks like this,

```
   33 0.573140941467E-01 0.112914262390E-03 0.255553577735E-02 0.497192659486E-04 0.141869181079E-01-0.147813598922E-03
   34 0.570076593453E-01 0.100112550891E-03 0.256427138318E-02-0.868691490164E-05 0.142821920093E-01-0.346011975369E-03
   35 0.715507714946E-01 0.316132133031E-03-0.106581466521E-01-0.920513736900E-04 0.138018668842E-01-0.212219497066E-03
```

Here 33, 34, 35 are integer values and it's followed by 6 double values. And these double values are not guaranteed to have space or some other delimiter between them. i.e., if a double is negative then it will have a "-" before it and this will take up the space. So basically, it's possible that all 6 double values will be together.

Now the challenge is, how to extract this gracefully?

What I tried:

```
String.Split(' ');
```

This will not work as a space is not guaranteed between the initial integer values and then the rest of double values.

This can be easily solved in C++ using `sscanf`.

```cpp
double a, b, c, d, e, f;

sscanf(string, "%d %lf%lf%lf%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
// here string contains a line of data from text file.
```

The text file containing double values are generated by a 3rd party tool and I have no control over its output.

Is there a way the integer and double values can be gracefully extracted line by line?

Comment: @CodeCaster - possibly the double values might be, but the starting integer is definitely not, as it starts from 1 and can potentially goes upto 2000 or more. And i need to extract both integer and all double values.

Comment: so this line here 0.316132133031E-03-0.106581466521E-01-0.920513736900E-04    .... does that mean you have 6 numbers, out of which 5 are negative ones?

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu - Yes, 6 double values, out of which 5 are negative.

Comment: @DonK, would you please clarify if it is Fixed Width Data or not?

Comment: `%d` + `double*` is definitely undefined behavior in C++.

Answer (score 10):

If I am seeing that right, you have a "Fixed Width Data" format. Than you can simply parse on that fact.

i.e. assuming the values are in a file `d:\temp\doubles.txt`:

```
void Main()
{
    var filename = @"d:\temp\doubles.txt";
    Func<string, string[]> split = (s) =>
    {
        string[] res = new string[7];
        res[0] = s.Substring(0, 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            res[i + 1] = s.Substring(2 + (i * 19), 19);
        }
        return res;
    };
    var result = from l in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                 let la = split(l)
                 select new
                 {
                    i = int.Parse(la[0]),
                     d1 = double.Parse(la[1]),
                     d2 = double.Parse(la[2]),
                     d3 = double.Parse(la[3]),
                     d4 = double.Parse(la[4]),
                     d5 = double.Parse(la[5]),
                     d6 = double.Parse(la[6])

                 };
    foreach (var e in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.i}, {e.d1}, {e.d2}, {e.d3}, {e.d4}, {e.d5}, {e.d6}");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
33, 0.0573140941467, 0.00011291426239, 0.00255553577735, 4.97192659486E-05, 0.0141869181079, -0.000147813598922
34, 0.0570076593453, 0.000100112550891, 0.00256427138318, -8.68691490164E-06, 0.0142821920093, -0.000346011975369
35, 0.0715507714946, 0.000316132133031, -0.0106581466521, -9.205137369E-05, 0.0138018668842, -0.000212219497066
```

PS: With your exact data, `int` should be allocating more space.

Comment: It's a good idea to use the double.Parse(..., NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), with the invariant format specification, because the decimal sepearator is always a dot here. When the code runs on a machine with different regional settings (e.g. german) it will fail to parse, if NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo is omitted.

Comment: no², it still is true - I just tried it. C# is tricky this way: it defaults to the locale settings of the current user! E.g. the first value "0.573140941467E-01" parses to the double value 57314094146,7 on my german system, when I omit NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.

Comment: OK then I stand corrected, you can include CultureInfo to your Parse.

Answer (score 6):

Solve this with a regular expression. My first shot is:

```
"[\s-+]\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d\d"
```

I just tried it this way:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1 {

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var fileContents =
                  "33 0.573140941467E-01 0.112914262390E-03 0.255553577735E-02 0.497192659486E-04 0.141869181079E-01-0.147813598922E-03"
                + "34 0.570076593453E-01 0.100112550891E-03 0.256427138318E-02-0.868691490164E-05 0.142821920093E-01-0.346011975369E-03"
                + "35 0.715507714946E-01 0.316132133031E-03-0.106581466521E-01-0.920513736900E-04 0.138018668842E-01-0.212219497066E-03";

            var rex = new Regex(@"[\s-+]\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d\d", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match match in rex.Matches(fileContents)) {
                double d = double.Parse(match.Value.TrimStart(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                Console.WriteLine("found a match: " + match.Value.TrimStart() + " => " + d);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

With this output (german localization, with comma as decimal separator):

```
found a match: 0.573140941467E-01 => 0,0573140941467
found a match: 0.112914262390E-03 => 0,00011291426239
found a match: 0.255553577735E-02 => 0,00255553577735
found a match: 0.497192659486E-04 => 4,97192659486E-05
found a match: 0.141869181079E-01 => 0,0141869181079
found a match: -0.147813598922E-03 => -0,000147813598922
found a match: 0.570076593453E-01 => 0,0570076593453
found a match: 0.100112550891E-03 => 0,000100112550891
found a match: 0.256427138318E-02 => 0,00256427138318
found a match: -0.868691490164E-05 => -8,68691490164E-06
found a match: 0.142821920093E-01 => 0,0142821920093
found a match: -0.346011975369E-03 => -0,000346011975369
found a match: 0.715507714946E-01 => 0,0715507714946
found a match: 0.316132133031E-03 => 0,000316132133031
found a match: -0.106581466521E-01 => -0,0106581466521
found a match: -0.920513736900E-04 => -9,205137369E-05
found a match: 0.138018668842E-01 => 0,0138018668842
found a match: -0.212219497066E-03 => -0,000212219497066
```

Comment: It is likely, he wants to treat each line as a separate "data record".

Comment: +1. But we can improve the Regex to make the exponent optional. Something like [\s-+]\d+\.\d+(E[-+]\d+)?

Comment: Ok, you are right. I added another solution, processing each line separately, making the exponent optional and including the leading int value for each line.

Answer (score 3):

I just went non optimal and replaced the "E-" string to something else while I replaced all the negative sign with a space and a negative sign (" -") then reverted all the "E-" values.

Then I was able to use split to extract the values.

```
private static IEnumerable<double> ExtractValues(string values)
{
    return values.Replace("E-", "E*").Replace("-", " -").Replace("E*", "E-").Split(' ').Select(v => double.Parse(v));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers i have seen so far are so complex. Here is a simple one without overthinking

According to @Veljko89's comment, i have updated the code with unlimited number support

```
    List<double> ParseLine(string line)
    {
        List<double> ret = new List<double>();

        ret.Add(double.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(' '))));
        line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1);

        for (; !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line); line = line.Substring(line.IndexOf('E') + 4))
        {
            ret.Add(double.Parse(line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf('E') + 4)));
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: What part of the answers did you find complex?Have you seen a programmer do code a separate line for each repetitive thing?

Comment: What you gonna do in a case when you have 15 variables? or 1000? With problems like this, try to think it that way ... tomorrow new file will come with a lot more needed variables and then you write code that will work for all cases

Comment: @CetinBasoz when you don't want to mess processor's cache line, yes, you can do it. but you are right about that because that's not the case here.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, also your code will not solve the problem OP was asking, because first integer value can go upper than 99 as OP states in the comment that "...it starts from 1 and can potentially goes upto 2000..."

Comment: @GurhanPolat, would you care to read my comment at the end? You can simply use the size you need. At the end, OP is dealing with a "FIXED WIDTH DATA" which needs to be handled with constraints.

Comment: @CetinBasoz would you care to read OP question in more detail, cause OP says that, the first integer value can go up to 2000. your code is useless in that case.

Comment: @GurhanPolat, Why would the code be useless? If you noticed OP said that in a comment. No way to know how big that might be, nor how much space is allocated in OP's file. You simply replace the 2 in the code whatever your allocated width is. It is dead simple.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, that code not working even for 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. i'm putting an end on this conversation because you are not getting that the data is not fixed width. if it was, OP would not have been asking the question in the first place. the integer value can be 1, 99, 111, 2000 or even 9999999. that makes the data width variable length. "9".Length=1, "999".Length=3. 1 != 3, so there is no fixed length data as you see.. "9 0.570076593453E-01...".Length != "2000 0.570076593453E-01..."

Comment: @GurhanPolat, OK it seems like you don't have an idea about "fixed width data" formats. You can search and learn about it either using "fixed width data" or SDF.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199441/discussion-between-gurhan-polat-and-cetin-basoz).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
public void ParseFile(string fileLocation)
{
   string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation);

   foreach(var line in lines)
   {
       string[] parts = var Regex.Split(line, "(?((?<!E)-)| )");

       if(parts.Any())
       {
          int first = int.Parse(parts[0]);

          double[] others = parts.Skip(1).Select(a => double.Parse(a)).ToArray();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If we can't use `string.Split` we can try to split by *regular expressions* with a help of `Regex.Split`; for a given `line`

```
string line = @"  33 0.573140941467E-01 0.112914262390E-03 0.255553577735E-02 0.497192659486E-04 0.141869181079E-01-0.147813598922E-03";
```

We can try

```
// Split either
//   1. by space
//   2. zero length "char" which is just after a [0..9] digit and followed by "-" or "+"
var items = Regex
  .Split(line, @" |((?<=[0-9])(?=[+-]))")
  .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item)) // we don't want empty parts 
  .Skip(1)                                    // skip 1st 33
  .Select(item => double.Parse(item));        // we want double

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

and get

```
0.573140941467E-01
0.112914262390E-03
0.255553577735E-02
0.497192659486E-04
0.141869181079E-01
-0.147813598922E-03
```

In case of a Text file we should split each line:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@" |((?<=[0-9])(?=[+-]))");

var records = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt") 
  .Select(line => regex
     .Split(line)
     .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
     .Skip(1)
     .Select(item => double.Parse(item))
     .ToArray());
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] test = new string[] {
     // your examples
     "  33 0.573140941467E-01 0.112914262390E-03 0.255553577735E-02 0.497192659486E-04 0.141869181079E-01-0.147813598922E-03",
     "  34 0.570076593453E-01 0.100112550891E-03 0.256427138318E-02-0.868691490164E-05 0.142821920093E-01-0.346011975369E-03",
     " 35 0.715507714946E-01 0.316132133031E-03-0.106581466521E-01-0.920513736900E-04 0.138018668842E-01-0.212219497066E-03",

     // Some challenging cases (mine)
     "    36 123+456-789    123e+78 9.9e-95 0.0001", 
  };

  Regex regex = new Regex(@" |((?<=[0-9])(?=[+-]))");

  var records = test
    .Select(line => regex
      .Split(line)
      .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
      .Skip(1)
      .Select(item => double.Parse(item))
      .ToArray());

  string testReport = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, records
    .Select(record => $"[{string.Join(", ", record)}]"));

  Console.WriteLine(testReport);
```

**Outcome:**

```
[0.0573140941467, 0.00011291426239, 0.00255553577735, 4.97192659486E-05, 0.0141869181079, -0.000147813598922]
[0.0570076593453, 0.000100112550891, 0.00256427138318, -8.68691490164E-06, 0.0142821920093, -0.000346011975369]
[0.0715507714946, 0.000316132133031, -0.0106581466521, -9.205137369E-05, 0.0138018668842, -0.000212219497066]
[123, 456, -789, 1.23E+80, 9.9E-95, 0.0001]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, processing each line by itself and including the int value:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string[] fileLines = {
            "33 0.573140941467E-01 0.112914262390E-03 0.255553577735E-02 0.497192659486E-04 0.141869181079E-01-0.147813598922E-03",
            "34 0.570076593453E-01 0.100112550891E-03 0.256427138318E-02-0.868691490164E-05 0.142821920093E-01-0.346011975369E-03",
            "35 0.715507714946E-01 0.316132133031E-03-0.106581466521E-01-0.920513736900E-04 0.138018668842E-01-0.212219497066E-03"
        };

        var rex = new Regex(@"\b([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+(?:E[+-]\d+)?)?)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        foreach (var line in fileLines) {

            var dblValues = new List<double>();
            foreach (Match match in rex.Matches(line)) {
                string strVal = match.Groups[1].Value;
                double number = Double.Parse(strVal, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                dblValues.Add(number);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("; ", dblValues));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The result/output is:

```
33; 0,0573140941467; 0,00011291426239; 0,00255553577735; 4,97192659486E-05; 0,0141869181079; -0,000147813598922
34; 0,0570076593453; 0,000100112550891; 0,00256427138318; -8,68691490164E-06; 0,0142821920093; -0,000346011975369
35; 0,0715507714946; 0,000316132133031; -0,0106581466521; -9,205137369E-05; 0,0138018668842; -0,000212219497066
```

Comment: Why are you getting -8,68691490164E-06 in output? Shouldn't that too be converted to a double value?

Comment: @ Don K: yes, it is converted. The original input String for this value was "-0.868691490164E-05". And the resulting double is then converted by the default ToString()-conversion for output, using my german locale settings (comma) and preferring the exponent E-06 (instead of E-05).